# Finite Fibers over closed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed field. If all fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ with $y$ closed point in $Y$ are finite, can one conclude that an arbitrary fiber (i.e. with $y$ not necessarily closed point) is finite?

Edit: By a fiber being finite I just mean it to consist of a finite number of points.

Comment: You should first think what you mean by a fiber being finite if it is not closed; I can see no obvious meaning. Think of $X=Y$ the affine line over your field and $f$ the identity; would you call the fiber over the generic point of $Y$ finite?

Comment: Dear @Marc, a fiber is finite if it contains a finite number of points: it is the naïve set-theoretic meaning. So in your example, yes, the fiber over the generic point is finite.  And Cyril's question has an affirmative answer: see my post  below.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks for brushing up my algebraic geometry a bit.

Comment: Dear @Marc: you are welcome. Actually it has happened to me too that, since scheme theory is so sophisticated, I couldn't believe that some concept or result was just what one naïvely would have guessed!

Comment: sorry for not immediately clarifying that point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all fibers of $f$ are finite ($f$ is quasi-finite).

Let $Z\subset Y$ the set of points with finite fibers.The key point is that $Z$ is also the set of points where $\dim f^{-1}(y)=0$.
Thus $Z$ is  a constructible set and since it contains all the closed points of $Y$, it is equal to $Y$.
You will find details  in the book by [Görtz-Wedhorn](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_Geometry_I.html?id=XEiLudn6sq4C&redir_esc=y), Remark 12.16